# Excel: Look up value in other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a solution to a little problem I'm having with vlookup and index/match. The problem I'm having is that the lookup value is from a cell containing a formula. If I punch in the number directly all is fine, but if I step into the error it tells me the cell contains a constant.

I've prepended the data with the English name of the formula.

> Vlookup -> FINN.RAD(220486;'Godkjente søknader'!D:J;7;USANN)   5,0
>     FINN.RAD(G266;'Godkjente søknader'!D:J;7;USANN) #I/T
>   Match ->   SAMMENLIGNE(220486;'Godkjente søknader'!D:D;0)  17,0
>     SAMMENLIGNE(G266;'Godkjente søknader'!D:D;0)    #I/T
>   G266:  HVIS(C266<>"";HVIS(ERFEIL(VENSTRE(C266;6));"";VENSTRE(C266;6));"")
>   C266:  220486 - Rentatool

All relevant cells are set as standard format.

[image: Screenshot]

Translating [Norsk to English](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=norsk-english.html):
FINN.RAD = VLOOKUP
USANN = FALSE
#I/T = #N/A
SAMMENLIGNE = MATCH
HVIS = IF
ERFEIL = IFERR or IFERROR
VENSTRE = LEFT

```
VLOOKUP(220486,'Godkjente søknader'!D:J,7,FALSE)   
VLOOKUP(G266,'Godkjente søknader'!D:J,7,FALSE)   
MATCH(220486,'Godkjente søknader'!D:D;0)   
MATCH(G266,'Godkjente søknader'!D:D;0)   
G266: IF(C266<>"",IF(ISERROR(LEFT(C266,6)),"",LEFT(C266,6)),"")
C266: 220486 - Rentatool
```

Comment: What is the output of this formula? HVIS(C266<>"";HVIS(ERFEIL(VENSTRE(C266;6));"";VENSTRE(C266;6));"") It seems that the Vlookup and Match are expecting something that the HVIS formula is not giving.

Answer (score 1):

Once I translated it, I could see the problem. the `LEFT` function returns a string and not a number. I'm betting column `D:D` is formatted as a number. The `MATCH` and `VLOOKUP` both fail because they're trying to find text in a range of number and Excel cares about the difference. Try changing from this:

```
LEFT(C266,6)
```

to this

```
VALUE(LEFT(C266,6))
```